# Solr - How does it work field boost?

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I'm new to Solr. Using Solr 1.4.1

I have a schema.xml that have this fields:

```
job_title
job_description
date_inserted
```

I need to give more importance to the "job_title" field. If for example I'm searching for the word "programmer" I need to show in the first place the results that have "programmer" in the "job_title" field ordered by date, then the results that have the word "programmer" in the "job_description" field.

It is possible to user order by date and boost together?

Please give me some clues on what I need to pay attention to do this.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is possible to use order by date and boost together?

No. Boosting relies on the default sorting by score desc. Setting a different sort field overrides sorting by scoring, therefore they're exclusive.

> I need to show in the first place the results that have "programmer" in the "job_title" field ordered by date, then the results that have the word "programmer" in the "job_description" field.

If you really want to do that, it's two queries: one by job_title, another by job_description.  But that's not how things are usually done in Solr. You run a single query with the appropriate boosting to influence scoring (instead of sorting), where you could for example use [function queries to boost newer documents](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents).

Then you give the user the option to sort by date or whatever field. As explained before, when the user sorts, he overrides any scoring and boosting.